# Skype API: is it able to add my own smiles or control message chat formatting and appearance?

Tags: skype

Is it able to add my own smiles or control message chat formatting and appearance?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Skype supports only its own [html codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Features_of_Skype#HTML_support_in_Skype) and only via SkypeKit not the desktop API.